# Html: How to select multiple talent types

Tags: html

Hi i have a code in which from dropdown i want to select multiple talent types & want to save to database
Code is

```
<div class="select-wrap">
                <select name="talent_type" id="talent_type">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Talent Type</option>
                    <?php foreach ($talentType['type'] as $typeT) { ?>
                        <option value=""><?php echo $typeT; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <label for="">Talent Type</label>
            </div>
```

Talent types are like actor, celebrity, musician etc.
I tried selecting using "multiple" attribute but that disturbs my frontent layout

[image]

What is the solution for it

Comment: How does it disturb your frontend layout? People can't help fix an issue if you don't tell them what it is.

Comment: The image in your question is clearly showing that you are using CSS. If you don't post the complete things then no one can solve it as per your actual need. And moreover trying to  answer something like this will always lead to Vote Down in the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you already tried using the `multiple` attribute and don't like how it breaks your layout but I'm afraid that is the only proper HTML way to do it. I suggest you use one of the multiple JS libraries created to solve this problem, I've had good experience with [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Comment: i guess this could be best option for me to try out. thanks for this link :-) Actually i am completely working on backend but forced to work for frontend as the frontend one is not available...any way thanks....

Answer (score -1):

You need to use 'multiple'

```
 <select name="talent_type" id="talent_type" multiple>
```

Comment: Read the question: _I tried selecting using "multiple" attribute but that disturbs my frontent layout_

Comment: can you post your css for this.

Answer (score -1):

To actually select multiple values in the select box you have to hold down your Control-Key (cmd on Mac) and then click inside the box...

Here is an example:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple